# Angular 6 - Add Bing Maps to Leaflet Maps

Tags: angular, leaflet, bing-maps

I am using `leaflet-bing-layer` plugin, in order to add a Bing based map with Leaflet.
Since I am using also OSM, I import both `leaflet` and `leaflet-bing-layer`.
The import statements are as follows:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as B from 'leaflet-bing-layer';
```

And the usage of leaflet inside the component `LeafletMapComponent`:

```
constructor () {
    this.baseMaps = {
      OpenStreetMap: L.tileLayer ("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, Tiles courtesy of <a href="https://hot.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team</a>'
      }),
      BingMap: B.tileLayer.bing(LeafletMapComponent.BING_KEY, {type: 'AerialWithLabels'})
    };
  }
```

Unfortunately, The ling `BingMap: B.tileLayer.bing(...` gets an error:
**Cannot read property 'bing' of undefined**

I didn't find any working example of Bing maps in Angular and Typescript, so I guess that there is something missing here.

Any thoughts of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `B`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import *leaflet-bing-layer* as following:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-bing-layer';
```

Then, you can add your Bing tile layer as following.

```
L.tileLayer.bing(LeafletMapComponent.BING_KEY).addTo(map);
```

This will throw you a type error that

```
property 'bing' does not exist on type 'tileLayer'
```

but you can overcome this error by defining L as custom type:

```
(L as any).tileLayer.bing(LeafletMapComponent.BING_KEY).addTo(map);
```

**Note:** I would not create the map on the constructor function. I would choose a lifecycle hook method instead, so that I can be sure that map is created after view is loaded.